# Argument of setHorizontalGroup()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

The method setHorizontalGroup is defined as: `setHorizontalGroup(GroupLayout.Group group)` .**I dont understand it's argument after going through this :**

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
layout.createSequentialGroup()
  .addComponent(c1)
  .addComponent(c2)
  .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
       .addComponent(c3)
       .addComponent(c4))
);
```

*How are we adding all this?*

Comment: One word of advice: don't try to understand, or worse, manually build, code that uses GroupLayout. GroupLayout is supposed to be used with a GUI designer (eg NetBeans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of method chaining. If you look at the methods of [`GroupLayout.Group`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.Group.html), you will notice that all the methods return a reference to the object on which it was called, so that you can chain multiple calls together.

The code you posted is equivalent to the following:

```
GroupLayout.Group group = layout.createSequentialGroup();
group.addComponent(c1);
group.addComponent(c1);
group.addGroup(...);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(group);
```

Since `group.addComponent(c1)` returns `group`, you can chain the calls and write `group.addComponent(c1).addComponent(c2)`.

Comment: @ casablanca I cannot understand this statement `GroupLayout.Group group = layout.createSequentialGroup();` createSequentialGroup() does not return reference to GroupLayout.Group.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: Both `SequentialGroup` and `ParallelGroup` are subclasses of `GroupLayout.Group`, so they can be passed anywhere a `Group` is required.